# How to change date format for all the items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, mapping

I have array `objproduct`, it has a field `lastseen` of type `Date` with format `DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a`. I need to change this date format to `MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a`.

I tried this, but looks my query is not correct

```
objproduct.forEach(element => { 
  moment(element.lastseen,'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a');
});
```

This is my sample array

```
{
    "lastseen":"DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a"
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 816,
},
{
    "lastseen":"DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a"
    "org": "AXC",
    "Id": 85427,
}
```

This output I am looking for

```
{
    "lastseen":"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a"
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 816,
},
{
    "lastseen":"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a"
    "org": "AXC",
    "Id": 85427,
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop you're creaing a new moment object and then calling the `.format()` method on it to return a string, however, you never actually use this returned string value. It's like writing an expression which evaluates to a value, but that value is never actually used:

```
objproduct.forEach(element => { 
  1 + 2; // Results in 3, but nothing ever happens with this number
});
```

The above idea is happening with your code. To use the value, you need to set the element's `lastseen` property to update it:

```
objproduct.forEach(element => { 
  element.lastseen = moment(element.lastseen,'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a');
});
```